# Can't conenct to a url

Tags: java, android, https, android-activity

I have a link where I'm providing 2 parameters and a php server side script is executing a query and writing them to my databae.

The problem is that in this specific case, it seems that I can't connect to teh url.

Here is my button xml file:

```
<Button 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:includeFontPadding="@+id/btnSubmit"   
 android:text="@string/btnSubmit"
 android:onClick="submitNewJ"
 />
```

Here is my click "listener":

```
public void submitNewJ(View view){
        new submitJ().execute();
    }
```

And here is the `submitJ` code:

```
public class submitJ extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{        

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try{
            String encodedName = URLEncoder.encode(Name,"UTF-8");
            String encodedBody = URLEncoder.encode(Body,"UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL("http://site123.com/android/J/sJ.php?Name="+encodedName+"&Body="+encodedBody);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }       
    }
```

And here is how I'm getting the strings:

```
EditText jN;
EditText jB;

String Name = "";
String Body = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_joke);

    jN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newName);
    jB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newBody);

    Name = jN.getText().toString();
    Body = jB.getText().toString();         
}
```

It seems that the connection is not working here(even when I'm using the same code in otehr activities). Where am I mistaking?
I know that I'm missing something super small, but I'm not able to spot it.

P.s. My service and link are 100% tested and working.

Comment: Where is your button click code?

Comment: @SimplePlan, It is here `android:onClick="submitNewJ"`

Comment: @SimplePlan `submitNewJ`

Comment: Put this `Name = jN.getText().toString(); Body = jB.getText().toString();`  under `submitNewJ(........)` and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you have in the example is probabbly for reference reasons, but mind that if it is using `https` protocol and you're reffering to a `http`, you will not get redirected to the correct link.
Everything in your code seems fine to me.
Just make sure that you're using the correct protocol.

Comment: I can't belive that I was missing such a small part! Nice guess! Huge thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move these lines from `onCreate()` method to `doInBackground()` method,

```
 Name = jN.getText().toString();
 Body = jB.getText().toString();
```

put them inside the doInBackground() method like below,

```
public class submitJ extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{        

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try{

         String Name = jN.getText().toString();        // move here and delete from the class
         String Body = jB.getText().toString();

        String encodedName = URLEncoder.encode(Name,"UTF-8");
        String encodedBody = URLEncoder.encode(Body,"UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL("http://site123.com/android/J/sJ.php?Name="+encodedName+"&Body="+encodedBody);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }       
}
```

Comment: I moved it but the problem seems to be that I can't access the url at all.

Comment: @SimplePlan, why to move it to submitNewJ() method ? There is no need to declare these variable at class level.

Comment: @Slim any reason for _DOWNVOTED_ my one question.

Comment: @Kedarnath any reason for _DOWNVOTED_ my one question.

Comment: @SimplePlan, Did you see the proof ?

Comment: @Kedarnath no. It seems that I can't access the url from the app. :(

Comment: any error logs ? have you given INTERNET permissions ?

Comment: @Kedarnath There are no errors. I have `INTERNET`and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` declared

Comment: @Slim, ok, what values you are passing in Name & Body variable ?

Comment: @Kedarnath I'm passing the text of 2 `EditText` fields

Comment: @Slim , of course I know that part, I am asking the `values`.

Comment: @Kedarnath It doesn't matter, but let's say `testVal1` and `testval2`

Comment: If I pass those values there it is returning `404`  , http://www.site123.com/android/J/sJ.php?Name=testVal1&Body=testVal2

Comment: @Kedarnath I think that slim pasted a site just for refference.